# SQL : how to exclude rows from count based on a public/private category?

Tags: sql

I have two tables (products and categories) with a many-to-many link table (products_categories). The query that I want to build should return only the products that belong to 5 or more public categories. Private categories have a '0' in the 'public' column of the 'categories' table, public categories have a '1'.

I can't find a way to ignore the private categories in the count. From my testing data, only Shovel and Lighter should make the cut. For the moment I get Motorbike, Shovel, Basketball, Football, Tennisball, Pickaxe and Lighter, because they belong to 5 or more categories (public and private).

The tables :

```
CREATE TABLE products(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  name VARCHAR(25),
  price INT,
  created_at DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE categories(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(25),
  public BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE products_categories(
  product_id INT,
  category_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);
```

The query :

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, COUNT(categories.id)
FROM products
INNER JOIN products_categories ON products.id = products_categories.product_id
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = products_categories.category_id
GROUP BY products.id
HAVING COUNT(categories.id) >= 5
```

Data for testing :

```
INSERT INTO categories VALUES
(1, 'Small', b'1'),
(2, 'Medium', b'1'),
(3, 'Large', b'1'),
(4, 'One-size', b'1'),
(5, 'Tool', b'1'),
(6, 'Sport', b'1'),
(7, 'Ball', b'1'),
(8, 'Camping', b'1'),
(9, 'Food', b'1'),
(10, 'Non-food', b'1'),
(11, 'High-return', b'0'),
(12, 'Low-return', b'0'),
(13, 'Dangerous', b'0');

INSERT INTO products VALUES
(1, 'Bicycle', 50, '2021-03-02'),
(2, 'Motorbike', 100, '2021-03-02'),
(3, 'Shovel', 10, '2021-03-02'),
(4, 'Skis', 20, '2021-03-02'),
(5, 'Tent-S', 20, '2021-03-02'),
(6, 'Tent-M', 30, '2021-03-02'),
(7, 'Tent-L', 30, '2021-03-02'),
(8, 'Basketball', 5, '2021-03-02'),
(9, 'Football', 5, '2021-03-02'),
(10, 'Tennisball', 2, '2021-03-02'),
(11, 'Pickaxe', 15, '2021-03-02'),
(12, 'Lighter', 1, '2021-03-02'),
(13, 'Bottle-S', 2, '2021-03-02'),
(14, 'Bottle-M', 3, '2021-03-02'),
(15, 'Bottle-L', 4, '2021-03-02');

INSERT INTO products_categories VALUES
(1, 4),
(1, 6),
(1, 10),
(1, 11),
(2, 4),
(2, 6),
(2, 10),
(2, 11),
(2, 13),
(3, 4),
(3, 5),
(3, 8),
(3, 10),
(3, 12),
(3, 13),
(4, 4),
(4, 6),
(4, 10),
(4, 11),
(5, 1),
(5, 8),
(5, 10),
(5, 12),
(6, 2),
(6, 8),
(6, 10),
(6, 12),
(7, 3),
(7, 8),
(7, 10),
(7, 12),
(8, 4),
(8, 6),
(8, 7),
(8, 10),
(8, 12),
(9, 4),
(9, 6),
(9, 7),
(9, 10),
(9, 12),
(10, 4),
(10, 6),
(10, 7),
(10, 10),
(10, 12),
(11, 4),
(11, 5),
(11, 10),
(11, 12),
(11, 13),
(12, 4),
(12, 5),
(12, 8),
(12, 10),
(12, 11),
(12, 13),
(13, 1),
(13, 8),
(13, 9),
(13, 12),
(14, 2),
(14, 8),
(14, 9),
(14, 12),
(15, 3),
(15, 8),
(15, 9),
(15, 12);
```

Comment: Did you try adding:`WHERE public = 1` to your query?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Of course, I tried adding it everywhere I thought it could make sense, but I couldn't get the expected result. I'm fairly new to SQL so I guess there must be something obvious that I'm not able to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(*)
FROM products p JOIN
     products_categories pc
     ON p.id = pc.product_id JOIN
     categories c
     ON c.id = pc.category_id
WHERE c.public = 1
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```

Comment: Well well... Your solution didn't give me the expected result, but you seemed confident so I checked again, and of course one of my categories was set to "private" when it should have been set to "public", hence why I couldn't get only two items to pass the test. I don't know how I didn't see it earlier. Thanks anyway.